# Specify behavior of a class member function based on type passed C++

Tags: c++, template-specialization

A simplified example of my code:

```
namespace Example 
{
    class A
    {
    public:

        template<typename T>
        void foo(T &val);

        template<>
        void foo<long>(long &val);
    };

    template<typename T>
    void A::foo(T &val) 
    {
        std::cout << "Generic Function: " << val << std::endl;
    }

    template<>
    void A::foo<long>(long &val)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialized Function: " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get an error like:

> explicit specialization in non-namespace scope

Why doesn't template specialization work here? How can I specify the behavior of a member function based on the type that's passed in?

Comment: It is supposed to work since C++17 at least (and maybe as DR for earlier versions). Which compiler are you using? I think GCC has not yet implemented this yet. (Assuming the missing `;` after the partial specialization declaration is a typo.)

Comment: However, you don't need to declare the explicit specialization inside the class definition if you are then anyway going to define it immediately afterwards. Note however that the ODR rule applies to explicit specializations as it does to normal functions. If you want this to be in a header, the specialization should be marked `inline`.

Comment: In my first comment I meant the missing `;` after the _explicit_, not _partial_, specialization. Also there are multiple other missing `;` and `Typename` should be `typename`. Please make sure that code you post doesn't contain irrelevant syntax errors that make the question harder to follow.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask]. Describe your problem before showing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need specialization for this, simple overloading will work fine (ie, remove the `template<>` from the 2nd `foo()`), eg:

```cpp
namespace Example 
{
    class A
    {
    public:

        template<typename T>
        void foo(T &val);

        void foo(long &val);
    };

    template<typename T>
    void A::foo(T &val) 
    {
        std::cout << "Generic Function: " << val << std::endl;
    }

    void A::foo(long &val)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialized Function: " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/wPLzDtdks)

Or, in C++17 and later, you can just get rid of the 2nd `foo()` altogether and use `if constexpr` inside the implementation of the 1st `foo()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace Example 
{
    class A
    {
    public:

        template<typename T>
        void foo(T &val);
    };

    template<typename T>
    void A::foo(T &val) 
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
            std::cout << "Specialized Function: " << val << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Generic Function: " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WWg8mqRz5)